# Count(*) over same External table gives different values in spark.sql() and hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am working on a AWS cluster with hive and spark. I have faced a weird situation previous day while I was running some ETL pyspark script over an external table in hive.

We have a control table which is having an extract date column. And we are filtering data from a staging table (managed table in hive, but location is s3 bucket)  based on the extract date  and loading to a target table which is an external table with data located in s3 bucket. We are loading the table as below

```
spark.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE target_table select * from DF_made_from_stage_table")
```

Now when I have checked the count(*) over target table via spark as well as via direct hive CLI, both are giving different count

in spark:

```
 spark.sql("select count(1) from target") -- giving 50K records
```

in hive:

```
 select count(1) from target -- giving a count 50k - 100
```

Note: There was happening an intermittent issue with statistics over external table which was giving -1 as count in hive. This we have resolved by running

```
ANALYZE TABLE target COMPUTE STATISTICS
```

But even after doing all these still we are getting  original_count-100 in hive where correct count in spark.

Comment: Can you execute “select count(*)” instead of “select count(1)” and check output from spark and hive ? Also please check output in hive after setting hive.compute.query.using.stats=false.

Comment: Does it work correctly in Hive when you `set hive.compute.query.using.stats=false` ? Also try spark.sql.statistics.size.autoUpdate.enabled=true.  Spark will update the table stats automatically.

Comment: MSCK REPAIR TABLE tabelName should work. If it does not work then you have to drop table (dropping external table won't delete data) and create same table again and then MSCK REPAIR TABLE tableName. Hopefully this should work.

Comment: @Shubhangi I have tried it. But still the same result. I am still getting 100 record count less in hive than in spark (spark count is the correct count)

Comment: @leftjoin I have tried both but no luck.I am still getting 100 record count less in hive

Comment: @asanand I have tried MSCK REPAIR TABLE, but no luck. Will check dropping the table

Comment: Please provide table DDL also

Comment: @leftjoin Yeah there was a mistake in the DDL used for external table. "skip.header.line.count"="1" was there in the DDL and we are having 100 output files. so 1 line each file were skipped , which caused  original count - 100 in hive while spark calculated it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake in the DDL used for external table. "skip.header.line.count"="1" was there in the DDL and we are having 100 output files. so 1 line each file were skipped , which caused original count - 100 in hive while spark calculated it correctly. Removed "skip.header.line.count"="1" and its giving count as expected now.